# SSD not found anymore (not listed by parted, nor lsblk etc, but bus found in lshw)

Tags: ssd, disk, devices

### EDIT: I think the SSD is juste dead, I bought a new one, all is fine, I'll see if I can get the data back (unlikely imo)

I have a dual-boot Windows 10 / Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop (HP Omen 15-5000 NF) with a PCI-e SSD (I think so). After putting my Windows in sleep mode, it was taking forever so I hard switched it off, not a good idea, but not so terrible I thought. Now, I can't boot, and, from a Live USB Ubuntu 18.04 I can't find the disk. By this I mean:

- no related `/dev/sdaX`
- `parted -l` does not list the SSD
- `lsblk` neither.

I each case, I only find the USB stick I'm on.
Note that the SSD was recognized before, even on Ubuntu, so I'm not sure it could be related to the BIOS.

Looking directly at the hardware with `lshw` I find some relevant entries, i.e. (the full output is here: https://pastebin.com/D8gYSQpC) :

```
[The USB Stick]
                    *-disk
                         description: SCSI Disk
                         product: UDisk
                         vendor: General
                         physical id: 0.0.0
                         bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0
                         logical name: /dev/sda
                         version: 5.00
                         size: 3840MiB (4026MB)
                         capabilities: removable
                         configuration: ansiversion=2 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
                       *-medium
                            physical id: 0
                            logical name: /dev/sda
                            size: 3840MiB (4026MB)
                            capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                            configuration: signature=00a4373e
                          *-volume
                               description: Windows FAT volume
                               vendor: SYSLINUX
                               physical id: 1
                               logical name: /dev/sda1
                               logical name: /cdrom
                               version: FAT32
                               serial: 2c1d-47da
                               size: 3837MiB
                               capacity: 3839MiB
                               capabilities: primary bootable fat initialized
                               configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=UBUNTU 18_0 mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro state=mounted


[...]

        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: d5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:27 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:d1600000-d16fffff
           *-storage
                description: SATA controller
                product: 88SS9183 PCIe SSD Controller
                vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
                version: 14
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
                resources: irq:33 ioport:3028(size=8) ioport:3034(size=4) ioport:3020(size=8) ioport:3030(size=4) ioport:3000(size=32) memory:d1600000-d16001ff memory:d1620000-d163ffff

[...]

        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:32 ioport:5088(size=8) ioport:5094(size=4) ioport:5080(size=8) ioport:5090(size=4) ioport:5060(size=32) memory:d171b000-d171b7ff
```

In other words, from `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
07:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SS9183 PCIe SSD Controller (rev 14)
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
09:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev c3)
```

I'm not sure what I can do, is there a way to explore the device? To manually assign a /dev/sdX file to this SATA Controller?
I've been looking in `/sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000\:00\:1f.2/` but I'm not used to it, so not sure what I can find/do.

Also, when booting I face this message: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WjFy7uts6Bbj7XJVAVrRfJzgZaBFMi_9

Any idea?
(I'm on this machine on live USB w/ Internet, we can even discuss on chat asap)

---

EDIT: Since I was considering changing the SSD I check the hardware, it's an M2 SSD (and the good news is that it can be changed)

Comment: If it is a PCIe SSD it's probably not called "sd*" in /dev but more likely "nvme*".

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure its a PCIe, but the `lspci` commands seems to say so?

Comment: Maybe its mSATA